# VS Ordered test on a remote machine TFS

Tags: tfs, coded-ui-tests, ordered-test

When you run the ordered test on a remote machine via the TFS, it does not work, even though it runs on the local machine.
viewing of the test file, the absolute path is visible, which spelled out the name of my computer, how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are using vNext Build system. You can add an [ordered test file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182631.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to your test project to control the test order. Refer to this link for details: [How to use Vnext build: ordered tests, distribute test, collect results](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/711c1f98-2d58-4b9b-805b-204ce6cc4d45/how-to-use-vnext-build-ordered-tests-distribute-test-collect-results?forum=tfsbuild).